# AttributeError: Open.Close Error while merging pptx presentation

Tags: python, pywin32, python-pptx

I am trying to use the function proposed by [@Zeynel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205450/how-can-i-combine-two-presentations-pptx-into-one-master-presentation) which is the following function:

```
    def mergePresentations(inputFileNames, outputFileName):

        Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
        outputPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add()
        outputPresentation.SaveAs(outputFileName)

        for file in inputFileNames:
            currentPresentation = Application.Presentations.Open(file)
            currentPresentation.Slides.Range(range(1, currentPresentation.Slides.Count + 1)).copy()
            Application.Presentations(outputFileName).Windows(1).Activate()
            outputPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
            currentPresentation.Close()

        outputPresentation.save()
        outputPresentation.close()
        Application.Quit()
```

However I keep getting the following error:
AttributeError: Open.Close
Where the ppt file Does not close by the win32com library and stops the whole merging process.
Any idea about the cause of the problem and how to solve?

Comment: Maybe try adding the optional readOnly=true parameter to the Open() call? You also try Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: @DS_London I tried both your solution but still I have the same problem. btw, this problem occurs more frequently when I have more presentations to merge.